# 1:1 Display in Box2D? (Flash AS3)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, box2d

Anyone know how to achieve a 1:1 display of box2d data?

I'm dividing all my values by a Physics.Scale value (30) but boxes I create like this:
 polyDef.SetAsBox(640 / Physics.scale, 32 / Physics.scale);

Are still showing up much larger than 640 pixels wide and 32 pixels high.

Weirdly, my AABB for the world is showing up perfectly at 640x480.

Anyone have any ideas?

This is how I create the debug draw data:

```
var debug : b2DebugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
var debugSprite : Sprite = new Sprite();

addChild(debugSprite);

debug.m_sprite = debugSprite;
debug.m_drawScale = Physics.scale;
debug.m_fillAlpha = 0.5;
debug.m_lineThickness = 1.0;
debug.m_drawFlags = 0xFFFFFFFF;

_world.SetDebugDraw(debug);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I'm just incredibly dumb.  SetAsBox takes half widths and half heights.  Oops.